# JQuery FadeIn and FadeOut with button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a button to show all content. I want a fadein on mouse enter, fadeout on mouseleave. when you click the button it disables the fade out, until clicked again and that re-enables it

Here is the Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uv4bxdxs/16/

```
<script>
   function Show() { 
    $('#div1h1').fadeIn();
    $('#div2h2').fadeIn();
    $('#div3h3').fadeIn();
}
</script>
<body>
    <button onclick="Show()">Show all</button>
    <div id="div1">
        <h1 id="div1h1">TEKST</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <h1 id="div2h2">TEKST</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <h1 id="div3h3">TEKST</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Then what do you want?

Comment: Hello, I am trying create a button that will keep all H1's FadIn. So when you click on the button you can just hover over all div's and the H1's will stay FadedIn. Im pretty bad in English sorry.

Comment: in summary, you want a fadein on mouse enter, fadeout on mouseleave. when clicked this disables the fade out, until clicked again and that re-enables it?

Comment: Exactly! I cant explain it so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to add a class to displayed elements on the button `click` event. The class purpose is to disable the fade-in-out functionality. When the button is clicked again that class is removed to re-enable fade-in-out effect.

```
var flag = true;
$('button').click( function() {
  if (flag) {
    $('#div1h1').fadeIn().addClass('shown');
    flag = false;
  }
  else {
    $('#div1h1').fadeOut().removeClass('shown');
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

See [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uv4bxdxs/24/)

Comment: this is probably the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you guys! Really appreciate it. :D

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code:

```
$(function() {
var showAllFlag = false;
var btnShowAll = $('#show-all');

$('body').on('mouseenter', 'div.info-box', function() {
    showTitle($(this))
}).on('mouseleave', 'div.info-box', function() {
    hideTitle($(this))
});

function showTitle(target) {
    target.find('h1').stop().fadeIn();
}

function hideTitle(target) {
    if (!showAllFlag) {
        target.find('h1').stop().fadeOut();
    }
}

function showAllTitles() {
    $('.info-box h1').show();
    showAllFlag = true;
}

btnShowAll.on('click', showAllTitles);
```

});

Or follow by this link: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/uv4bxdxs/18/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works but now I want a fadein on mouse enter, fadeout on mouseleave. when you click the button it disables the fade out, until clicked again and that re-enables it. I dont know how to do that. Can you help my? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't trigger the fadein if its already visible?

```
  $('#div1').not(":visible").hover(function() { 
     $('#div1h1').fadeIn(); 
  },
```

<strike>edit - My bad i didn't see that comma :), gimme a second</strike>

Comment: Thank you very much! I am new to Jquery and Javascript so this was probably a noobie question :P. Thanks Agian.

Comment: I want a fadein on mouse enter, fadeout on mouseleave. when you click the button it disables the fade out, until clicked again and that re-enables it. I dont know how to do that. Can you help my? :)

Comment: Yes I will give it another go shortly, currently at work ;)

Comment: Ah, Thank you for all your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#div1').hover(function() { 
        $('#div1h1').fadeIn(); 
    });
    });
    $(function() {
    $('#div2').hover(function() { 
        $('#div2h2').fadeIn(); 
    });
    });
    $(function() {
    $('#div3').hover(function() { 
        $('#div3h3').fadeIn(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! the solution of Josh Harrison also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just want the H1 to fade in and for them to stay visible on hover, just have the following code:

```
<script>
   function Show() { 
    $('#div1h1').fadeIn();
    $('#div2h2').fadeIn();
    $('#div3h3').fadeIn();
}
</script>
<body>
    <button onclick="Show()">Show all</button>
    <div id="div1">
        <h1 id="div1h1">TEKST</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <h1 id="div2h2">TEKST</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <h1 id="div3h3">TEKST</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

The JSFiddle link you provided has an extra JavaScript section which is causing the H1 to fade out on hover.